# Not calling the right scene objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

Hi I'm pretty new to objective C and haven't worked much with the SpriteKit yet. I'm trying to figure out why my GameViewController isn't firing my MenuScene.m.

This is from my GameViewController

```
#import "MenuScene.h"

@implementation GameViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

MenuScene* scene = (MenuScene*)[SKScene nodeWithFileNamed:@"MenuScene"];

// Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

SKView *skView = (SKView *)self.view;

// Present the scene
[skView presentScene:scene];

skView.showsFPS = YES;
skView.showsNodeCount = YES;
}
@end
```

This is from my MenuScene.m

```
- (void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view 
{
NSLog(@"In MenuScene.m");
CGSize playButtonSize = CGSizeMake(100, 100);
_playButton = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor redColor] size:playButtonSize];
_playButton.position = CGPointMake(self.size.height * .5, self.size.width*.5);
_playButton.name = @"playButtonNode";
_playButton.zPosition = 1.0;
[self addChild:_playButton];
}
```

What I get is a washed out grey color background with nothing else and nothing gets printed on the console so I know its not calling the didMoveToView method in my MenuScene.m. Also if I change this line

```
MenuScene* scene = (MenuScene*)[SKScene nodeWithFileNamed:@"MenuScene"];
```

to this

```
GameScene *scene = (GameScene *)[SKScene nodeWithFileNamed:@"GameScene"];
```

it will correctly call the didMoveToView method in the GameScene file. Sorry for the silly question but everything I try wont work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to guess that although your code *casts* `[SKScene nodeWithFileNamed:@"MenuScene"]` to a MenuScene, it is *not* in fact a MenuScene and so no MenuScene code runs.

Comment: It's easy to find out: right after you have set `MenuScene* scene`, log it and see what it is. I'm betting it's `nil`.

Comment: Yeah you're right I just logged it and scene's value was null. How would I go  about fixing that

Comment: The hint is "Don't assume." Your code just _guesses_ that `[SKScene nodeWithFileNamed:@"MenuScene"]` will be a MenuScene. Programming is not about guessing. (My answer had to guess, because your code guessed. I guessed right, your code guessed wrong.)